# How is he playing a D7 in the key of C major?

Tags: chord-progressions

Why does it work when Jimmie Rodgers plays D7 in the key of C? how does the vocal melody still function?

In the first two songs he plays D7 and it works well. It's not borrowed from the parallel minor and it doesn't seem to be modal interchange. He also plays an A7 in the 2nd song which makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's such a common occurrence, it's taken for granted. Here, in key C, D7 is V/V - the dominant of the dominant. The D7 leads diectly to G, which then does the same into C.

I suppose, reluctantly, at a push, it could be said to come from the relative minor Am, which, in its mantle of melodic minor, contains that F♯.

You seem fixated into the 'rule' that everything in a piece must be diatonic, or else it's breaking that 'rule' - which never existed anyway. Just about any chord can be/will be/ used in any piece in any key. With often, no need for justification - only that it works! We can't make rules and reasons for every chord that's non-diatonic. With only twelve notes to play with - literally - there's going to be times when some 'wrong' notes come out to play.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127064/discussion-on-answer-by-tim-how-is-he-playing-a-d7-in-the-key-of-c-major).

Answer (score 2):

> In the first two songs he plays D7 and it works well. It's not borrowed from the parallel minor and it doesn't seem to be modal interchange.

Add to the list of sources of chromatic chord, along with *borrowed* chords, the *secondary dominants*. Those being the dominants of the diatonic chords other than the tonic and the leading tone triad.

> He also plays an A7 in the 2nd song which makes no sense to me.

Any diatonic triad not the tonic and not the leading tone triad can take a secondary dominant. So, `A7` is a dominant to a `D` chord, assuming the song is in `C` major, the diatonic `D` chord is `D` minor. `A7` is the secondary dominant of `Dm` in `C` major. In Roman numerals the `D` minor chord is `ii`. To show the secondary dominant relationship use a slash, for example `C: V7/ii`, which in English would read like "in `C` major the secondary dominant seventh chord of the two chord."

In `C` you can have secondary dominants: `V/ii`, `V/iii`, `V/IV`, `V/V`, `V/vi`. Five chords.

For completeness, the borrowed chords would be `i`, `iio`, `♭III`, `iv`, `v`, `♭VI`, `♭VII`. Of those chords which are major/minor triads, they too could take secondary dominants.

For jazz/pop labels, then a fairly complete list of "common" chords for `C` major is: `C`, `Cm`, `C7`, `Dm`, `D7`, `Ddim`, `E♭`, `E♭7`, `Em`, `E7`, `F`, `Fm`, `F7`, `G`, `Gm`, `G7`, `A♭`, `Am`, `A7`, `B♭`, `B♭7`, `Bdim`. 22 chords. Again, that is *not* a complete list. It's just the diatonic and borrowed chords and their secondary dominants.

Just for sake of comparison, think about chord types major, minor, and diminished triads, plus the dominant seventh chord, for 4 types. Those four types on  each of the 12 chromatic pitch classes is 4 x 12 = 48, then add three fully diminished seventh chords for a total of 51 chords. Again, not literally every chord, but a fairly complete list of chromatic harmony.

22 "common" chords in a given key from a list of 51 "chromatic" chords is slightly less than half of the chromatic chord list. By that measure quite a lot of chromatic chords are commonly used while still clearly being "in a key!" This is how you can commonly have chords like `D7` or `A7` in the key of `C` major.

Comment: "A key is the most direct way to open a door ... not the only way."
- © Randy Zeitman, 2017

Answer (score 0):

A key just defines the general harmonic family for a piece.  There's nothing about playing in a key that requires you to only use its notes, and it's a rare piece indeed that sticks to the signature entirely.

In this case, D7 makes a mini-modulation to the V chord, G.  You could play d-minor7 if you wanted, but the dominant pushes up toward that G a little more strongly.